# One inline Div shifted lower than rest

Tags: css, html

[image: One Div lower than others]

```
<div class='noshop-products-div'><div class='noshop-products' align='center'> 

<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product '> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgiver.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver DVD -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product '> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgiverdvd.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver DVD</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver CD -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product '> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgivercd.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver CD</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver Workbook -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product '> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgiverworkbook.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver Workbook</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver for Teens -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product '> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgiverteens.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver for Teens</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 


<!-- -------------------- NoShop Item: The Dream Giver Library / The Dream Giver for Parents -------------------- --> 
<div class='noshop-product last-product'> 
    <div class=noshop-product-imagebox  width=83 style="width:83px;" > 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><img class=noshop-product-image  width=83 style="width:83px;"  src="./wp-content/themes/mingle-theme/parallelus-mingle/assets/images/skins/skin-7/bw/products/dreamgiver/dreamgiverparents.png" /></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class=noshop-product-textbox> 
        <a href="http://jesper.angelo.net/wordpress/noshop/" /><div class=noshop-product-title>The Dream Giver for Parents</div></a> 
        <div class=noshop-product-desc> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
        <div class=noshop-product-subtable> 
            &nbsp;
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
</div><!--End Products DIV -->

/* No Shop Categories */ 
.The_Dream_Giver_Library {
    background: #cf2426;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cf2426 0%, #ac1e1f 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cf2426), color-stop(100%,#ac1e1f));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cf2426 0%,#ac1e1f 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cf2426 0%,#ac1e1f 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cf2426 0%,#ac1e1f 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cf2426', endColorstr='#ac1e1f',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, #cf2426 0%,#ac1e1f 100%);
}

/* No Shop Products */
.noshop-category {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.noshop-products-div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.noshop-products {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 190px;
    background: #fefefe;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%, #d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefefe), color-stop(100%,#d3d3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefefe', endColorstr='#d3d3d3',GradientType=0 );
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fefefe 0%,#d3d3d3 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    margin-top: 10px;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: cente;
}
.noshop-product {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 170px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border-right: 1px solid #939598;
}
.last-product {
    border-right: none;
}
.noshop-product-imagebox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 83px;
}
.noshop-product-imagebox img {
    height: 115px;
}
.noshop-product-textbox {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 15px;
}
.noshop-product-textbox a, .noshop-product-textbox a:visited, .noshop-product-textbox a:link {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You simply need this:

```
.noshop-product {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

There are two reasons for your problem: the default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, and the text inside *the other* `.noshop-product`s all have two lines of text.